# Apply an added reference to all windows forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to apply the reference " using mysql.data " to all windows forms in a project by not going to each form and typing it manually? Like an option from the solution explorer.

Comment: You could ask someone else to do it.

Comment: Never tried, but you could try using a partial class to do it.

Comment: This is called importing a namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

- Edit -> Find And Replace -> Find in Files
- in Find what box write: `using System;`
- in Replace with box write: `using System;\r\nusing mysql.data;`
- in Find options group check `use regular expressions` and in Look at these file types add `*.cs`